# Check to see if today is between a range of dates in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Using Excel, I am trying to use an if(and(date1<=TODAY(),TODAY()>=date2), true, false) function, and using the TODAY() function, yet when I check it with a past date, it always returns the true value of the function.

Comment: Change the `>=` to `<=`. Also, the `IF` is superfluous, just use `AND`, which already returns a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have your >= and <= backwards for your dates.
Try:

```
=IF(AND(TODAY() >= "DATE1", TODAY() <= "DATE2"
```

Also check to see if your using absolute references anywhere (i.e. $A$2) in your formula.